# Vim remap to change directory

Tags: gvim, gvimrc

I'd like to have a shortcut in gvim to switch directories. I have the following in my gvimrc.

```
"noremap <F6> :cd "c:\\project\\working\\code"<return>"
```

I can't get it to work, though. What could be the problem?

Comment: Presumably the outer set of quotes aren't really there, since they would probably start a comment or if not, confuse the inner set.

Comment: I don't have the outer set of quotes. My rc file only has noremap <F6> :cd "c:\\project\\working\\code"<return> and it was not working. Anyways I got it working. It ain't the double backslash or the forward slash, it was the quotes in the path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of the quotes around the directory
2. Change `\\` to `/`. Even on Windows, vim can use `/` to navigate directories

New command

```
noremap <F6> :cd C:/Project/Working/Code<CR>
```